# How to extract the data from an ImmutableMultiDict

Tags: python, flask

I receive my data as an ImmutableMultiDict

`ImmutableMultiDict([('slim[]', '{"server":[{"status":"SUCCESS"}],"meta":{},"input":{"name":"sample-img.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":41319,"width":400,"height":300},"output":{"width":400,"height":300,"image":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ....`

I convert that to a dict

```
data = dict(request.form)
```

After converting to a dict, I end up with the data in this format.

```
{
'imageUploaded': 
    ['{     
    "server":[{"status":"SUCCESS"}],
    "meta":{},
    "input":{
                "name":"sample-img.jpg",
                "type":"image/jpeg",
                "size":41319,
                "width":400,
                "height":300
            },
    "output":{"width":400,"height":300,"image":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j//WmZyP/2Q=="
        },
    "actions":
            {
                "rotation":0,
                "crop":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":400,"height":300,"type":"manual"},
                "size":
                {
                    "width":640,"height":640
                }
            }
        }']
}
```

I have tried

```
data = json.dumps(dict(request.form))
a = json.loads(data)
print(a['imageUploaded']['output']['image'])
```

But I get this error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Why do you convert it to a `dict`?

Comment: Thought it would be access the json elements in list that way. Please let me know if there is another way to extract the same information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is the `data`?  (I assume you are pretty-printing it because you can't have multi-lined `'string'` values)

```
{
'imageUploaded': 
    ['{
```

Then you need `data['imageUploaded'][0]` to get the first element of that array.

That appears to be a JSON string, so parse that

```
import json
inner_data = data['imageUploaded'][0]
inner_data = json.loads(inner_data)
```

And then, you can `inner_data['output']['image']`

[**Sample Run**](https://repl.it/EPOo/0)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. inner_data['output']['image'] is printing image and everything after it all well.

Comment: Should print `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j//WmZyP/2Q==`

Comment: Yes, it is working. My bad, I had another print statement after that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use for loop to iterate over dictionary values, and get multi dictionary keys for a specific value.